# getting an illegal state exception

Tags: android

I have this login acitivity that fetches the values from a server.i am able to retreive the values correctly but i am getting an illegal state exception.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
code:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

String[] classname= new String[10];
String[] pass= new String[10];
EditText class_name,password;
boolean flag;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    class_name =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.class_name_et);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass_et);
    //invalid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

}
public void login(View v)
{
    String temp=getServerData(KEY_121);
    String un= class_name.getText().toString();
    String pas= password.getText().toString();
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {

        if(classname[i].equalsIgnoreCase(un)&&pass[i].equalsIgnoreCase(pas))
        {
            Log.i("success",""+classname[i]);
            flag=false;
            Intent i1=new Intent(StartActivity.this,Subect_Names.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    }
    if(flag)
    {
        Log.i("fail","failed to login");
    }

}

public static final String KEY_121 = "http://192.168.1.7/class_login.php";

private String getServerData(String returnString) {

   InputStream is = null;

   String result = "";
    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ClassName","nand"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pass","921279"));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);                   
                    classname[i]=   json_data.getString("ClassName");
                    pass[i]=    json_data.getString("Pass");
                    Log.e("test",""+classname[i]);

                    //Get an output to the screen
                    returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            }
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return returnString;
}
```

}Logcat:

```
 09-26 18:52:42.294: E/test(328): Rohit
09-26 18:52:42.294: E/test(328): Nanda
 09-26 18:52:42.294: E/test(328): abc
 09-26 18:52:42.303: I/success(328): Nanda
 09-26 18:52:42.323: D/AndroidRuntime(328): Shutting down VM
 09-26 18:52:42.323: W/dalvikvm(328): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at org.example.attendance.StartActivity.login(StartActivity.java:52)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     ... 11 more
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-26 18:52:42.353: E/AndroidRuntime(328):     ... 15 more
 09-26 18:52:44.523: I/Process(328): Sending signal. PID: 328 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please add the logcat... Or at least the line where the exception is thrown...

Comment: @ppeterka66 added the logcat

Answer (score 1):

You error is in this line of code

```
org.example.attendance.StartActivity.login(StartActivity.java:52)
```

Comment: can u please point out the line in code that as the error?because i am not able find the error in line 52.

Comment: Is that the complete class file? Including all your imports?

Comment: it is giving an error at the line-"if(classname[i].equalsIgnoreCase(un)&&pass[i].equalsIgnoreCase(pas))" but executing the log.i command inside this loop

Comment: Looking more into your logs there is also a NullPointerException looks like the array has a null value, not sure though. May be debug to check the values in the array classname[i] or pass[i].